# Facebook Swift (facebook-sdk-swift) error after adding pod

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sdk

I did try the new released Facebook SDK for Swift [Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift), added but after

> pod 'FacebookCore'

But after

> pod install

I get a error, see attached image

[image: error]

Are there more steps needed?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook SDK in Swift is still in Beta. You should wait until it is out of beta.

This is a post from facebook:
Since Swift is still under active development, the Facebook SDK for Swift Beta supports Swift 2.2.1 and 2.3, which gives you the ability to submit apps to the Apple App Store today. Later this year we will update the Facebook SDK for Swift when Swift 3 reaches GM.